# Copy values from a column into the same cell on different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a form that I need to fill out multiple times in Excel.

Each sheet is the blank form, and I've got a final helper sheet with a list of addresses in a column.

How can I copy each address once per sheet into the same cell?

Comment: copy =('sheetname'!A1) to each of the sheets, where sheetname is the helper sheet, and A1 is the column+row you want to copy. Not posting as answer because I'm guessing there's a faster way.

Comment: I have to do this 139 times...I was hoping to do this quickly rather than one by one that many times.

Comment: "each sheet is a blank form", copy to 1 sheet and copy that sheet 138 more times?

Comment: I would end up with 139 identical addresses if I did that. They're all different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done. You can put a formula in the same cell on multiple sheets by selecting all the sheets first. Right click on a tab and click "Select All Sheets". Hold down Ctrl and unselected any sheets you don't want. Now you can put a formula in a cell in all these sheets, for example, `A1=Sheet1!A1`. The problem here, of course, is that this will give you the same address on every sheet.

To get different addresses, I would do it this way:

1. In a column next to your addresses, Fill in the sheet names where you want the address (e.g. "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc.).
2. In your formula (for every sheet) use the INDEX-MATCH construct. The MATCH formula will need to match the sheet name. You can get the sheet name using this formula `=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))` (Note, the spreadsheet must be saved for this to work.)
3. If I assume your addresses are on Sheet 1 in Column A, and the sheet names are in Column B, then the formula to put in the 139 sheets would be as follows:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,MATCH(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))),Sheet1!B1:B4))`

Comment: I used this method, but basically instead of using the `INDEX` function I used `VLOOKUP` based on the sheet name. This would work too, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your HelperSheet has the column with addresses in column A, starting in Cell A1.
What you'll need to do on your "Form" sheets is have a helped cell to drive an INDEX formula that will look up the addresses on Helpersheet column A.

e.g. let's call the first form sheet "Form1", in cell A1 put the value "1". where you want the address to appear in the form, put `=INDEX(HelperSheet!A:A,A1,0)`
This will look up the value in Helpersheet!A1

For your next form sheet, change the helper cell to "2",same index formula will lookup value in Helpersheet!A2

Hope this makes sense? (I'd post pics but my rep isn't high enough yet)
Cheers